# How do I delete the Google App Engine SDK from my mac?

Tags: macos, google-app-engine

I installed the Google App Engine on my mac some time ago and I'm not using it now. The Google Updater thing asks me to update the GAE every now and then and it's getting on my nerves. How do I uninstall the GAE? I can't find anything to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

On mac, find the launch agent's plist file at:

~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.google.keystone.agent.plist

or

/Library/LaunchAgents/com.google.keystone.agent.plist

Delete the file, or disable it with

```
<key>Disabled</key> <true/>
```

Note that I think this software updater affects other Google things too, like Picasa.

Comment: Can't try this now, since I formatted and installed Snow Leopard. Thanks for the input anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specifically about GAE SDK, but Eclipse is **modular** and keeps its plugins under `/path-to/eclipse/plugins`. Some plugins are really easy to install/remove just by pasting/deleting them into/from that folder.

**Example:**

`/opt/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle.1.3.3_1.3.3.v201004211208`