# How Do I uninstall Google App Engine SDK

Tags: macos, google-app-engine

Ever since I installed the Google App Engine Launcher on my Mac (OS X Lion), I've been getting periodic alerts from the Google App Engine SDK about auto-updating, and I haven't been able to figure out how to uninstall/disable it.

I've looked at [How do I delete the Google App Engine SDK from my mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175491/how-do-i-delete-the-google-app-engine-sdk-from-my-mac) , but I couldn't find the file that was listed in the answer.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I think it has to do with ~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/Actives/com.google.GoogleAppEngineLauncher , but I don't want to mess around with files without being sure..

Comment: See "sudo gcloud components list" answer below; better than current accepted answer.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you only wish to **disable** the the App Engine autoupdate feature, do the following ([source](http://www.arthurkoziel.com/2008/07/26/the-google-software-update-agent/)):

*Either* delete the file:

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.google.Keystone.Agent.plist
```

*Or* add a new `Disabled` property to it (if you wish to keep the file):

```
<key>Disabled</key>
<true/>
```

If you wish to uninstall **Google Software Update** completely, do the following ([source](http://support.google.com/installer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=100386)):

1. Uninstall any Google programs you currently have installed on your computer.
2. Open a Terminal window by going to Applications > Utilities in Finder.
3. Google Software Update can be uninstalled for a specific user or for your whole system. Paste one of the following commands in Terminal:

Uninstall for a specific user:

`~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resources/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.app/Contents/Resources/install.py --uninstall`

Uninstall for the whole system: (needs root access):

`sudo /Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resources/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.app/Contents/Resources/install.py --uninstall`

**Note that the two commands listed above are supposed to be on one line**

Of course then it goes without saying that you can delete the directory that you chose to store the App Engine Python SDK.

Also note that if your `.plist` file is in binary format, you'll need to convert it to XML and then back when you're done ([source](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050430105126392)).

From binary to XML:

```
plutil -convert xml1 some_file.plist
```

From XML to binary:

```
plutil -convert binary1 some_other_file.plist
```

Comment: this works great, but it looks like if you run google chrome afterwards, it tries to re-install the GoogleSoftwareUpdate app.

Comment: Just to be clear, "Google programs" doesn't include google chrome right?

Comment: Software update reminders for software you never use are very irritating.

Comment: Command not found for ~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resources/GoogleSoftwareUpdateAgent.app/Contents/Resources/install.py. Can I just delete the entire installation folder?

Answer (score 39):

I installed Google App Engine without any Google Updater (December 2012).
To remove all files which GAE installed run this:

```
rm -rf /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app 
sudo find -L /usr/local/bin -type l -exec rm -- {} +
sudo rm /usr/local/google_appengine
```

The first line depends on the location of your GoogleAppEngineLauncher of course.
The second line removes all invalid symlinks of the /usr/local/bin directory

Comment: thanks @JohnCoogan for the edit. I think it's better that way

Comment: is that quite dangerous if you've got other stuff in /usr/local?

Comment: @StefanFisk: I assume that you refer to the second line. This only removes invalid symlinks in `/usr/local/bin/` (as written in the explanation below)

Answer (score 4):

In Mac Terminal by typing:

```
$ sudo gcloud components list
```

You get a list of what you installed and not installed:

```
The following are the components available through the Google Cloud 
SDK.  You may choose to install one or more of the pre-configured 
packages (which contain everything you need to get started), and/or 
any of the individual components below.
......
| Not Installed | gcloud app Python Extensions                  | app-engine-python           |   6.6 MB |
| Installed     | BigQuery Command Line Tool                    | bq                          |   < 1 MB |
| Installed     | Cloud DNS Admin Command Line Interface        | dns                         |   < 1 MB |
| Installed     | Cloud SDK Core Libraries                      | core                        |   1.3 MB |
| Installed     | Cloud SQL Admin Command Line Interface        | sql                         |   < 1 MB |
| Installed     | Cloud Storage Command Line Tool               | gsutil                      |   3.0 MB |
| Installed     | Compute Engine Command Line Interface         | compute                     |   < 1 MB |
| Installed     | Compute Engine Command Line Tool (deprecated) | gcutil                      |   < 1 MB |
......
```

The last column of the above list contains COMPONENT_IDs(..., "app-engine-python", "bq", "dns", ...)."age-java" is one of the COMPONENT_IDs, which I did not shown in the above list.

To remove an installed component, use its COMPONENT_ID. For example, to remove gae-java, you say:

```
$ sudo gcloud components remove gae-java
```

And gae sdk for java will be removed:

```
The following components will be removed:
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| App Engine SDK for Java                     | 1.9.17 | 161.2 MB |
| App Engine SDK for Java (Platform Specific) | 1.9.10 |   < 1 MB |
-------------------------------------------------------------------

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y

|- Creating update staging area                             -|
|============================================================|

|- Uninstalling: App Engine SDK for Java                    -|
|============================================================|
|- Uninstalling: App Engine SDK for Java (Platform Speci... -|
|============================================================|

Creating backup and activating new installation...

Done!
```

Not sure if it is what you are looking for. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is by far the cleanest and most straightforward way to clean it up. Thank! Wish I could select this as "acceped answer"

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the **google-cloud-sdk** folder.

**EDIT:**

As I can understand, previous answers are to disable automatic updating, but this will also affect other google applications like google chrome, for which you might probably will not want to do that, though.

During installation '.bash_profile' gets written with something like:

```
# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
source '/Users/<your_name>/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'

# The next line enables bash completion for gcloud.
source '/Users/<your_name>/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'
```

So in conclusion, just delete the folder which most probably will be located in your root, unless you specified something else during installation.

Comment: In what way is "delete a specific folder" not an answer to the question "how do I uninstall something"?

Answer (score -1):

To Uninstall google app engine from Windows and re install it go to Control Panel -> Uninstall programs -> Google App Engine.
The program will be uninstalled.
Now in search bar in Windows, type google app engine... if you get any related files go to that folder and delete it from there also. This results in successful Uninstall.After this if you wish you can re-install it.