# How do I get the Google App Engine installer to stop trying to install?

Tags: macos, google-app-engine

I downloaded the Google App Engine installer and installed GAE.  Now I get a periodic popup asking me if I would like to update it. There doesn't seem to be any way to turn it off.

How does this thing have hooks into my OS?

```
bash-3.2# pwd
/usr/lib/cron/tabs
bash-3.2# ls -la
total 0
drwx------  2 root    wheel   68 May 18  2009 .
drwxr-xr-x  8 daemon  wheel  272 Sep  4  2011 ..
bash-3.2#
```

Nope.

```
$ ls /etc/crontab
ls: /etc/crontab: No such file or directory
```

Nope.

It doesn't seem to be cron waking it up.  Any ideas of how to turn it off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's using [launchd](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) to schedule updates. Its configuration file should be in your user's LaunchAgents directory (`~/Library/LaunchAgents/`). It can just be disabled (as opposed to just deleting the whole thing) by [modifying the plist file to add a disabled key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9196350/2167797) as such:

```
open ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.google.keystone.agent.plist
```

Then add the disabled key:

```
<key>Disabled</key>
<true/>
```

Comment: well it turned out to be in the system-wide /Library/LaunchAgents/ , but otherwise I found it; now to see if it works, which I suppose I will never notice if it does unless I think about it; thanks