# How do I uninstall Google Cloud SDK in Windows

Tags: windows, google-app-engine, uninstallation, gcloud

I have installed the Google Cloud SDK in Windows 7 as instructed in the [Google Cloud SDK document](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/). And its installed in `C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK`.

But I haven't seen any option to completely uninstall this SDK in windows control panel.

Comment: I believe the cloud SDK is just a bunch of scripts and binaries, so deleting the installation folder should do the trick. At least that's how it is using cygwin on windows, which i generally recommend for bash/shell awesomeness on windows.

Comment: I found it in Add Remove Programs. Install Dir was in AppData. Win10

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the latest SDK, Under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK" you should find an uninstaller (uninstaller.exe). Just execute it.

Comment: If you choose to show the details from the uninstall, you'll see it adds a 'delete on reboot'. Make sure you reboot for good measure, before reinstalling

Comment: The uninstaller.exe should be available if you used the interactive installer - https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-interactive (which I recommend). If you installed using a .zip then the answer from @shawmanz32na is a better guide for uninstalling. Both approaches are a good guide for Windows 10

Comment: in my Windows 10 it was installed in C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK. I have Bash installed, so I ran `which gcloud` to find this folder,

Answer (score 5):

I have also been struggling with this.

As far as I can tell, the Google App Engine SDK Windows installer installs a whole bunch of binaries into `C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK`, installs Python 2 (2.7.6 as of this post's writing), creates a `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON` environment variable, and updates your `PATH` variable to reference the Python and Cloud SDK locations.

The Cloud SDK Core Command Line Tools (`gcloud`) can assist you with removing most of the binaries. It's been suggested [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9189054/1342760) that these binaries can just be deleted, but I uninstalled them one-by-one, just to be safe. To do this (taken from [L.H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4463538/l-h)'s post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27997727/1342760)), launch the Google Cloud SDK Shell from your Start menu, and run `gcloud components list` to see all the SDK components. Each can be removed by running `gcloud components remove [COMPONENT_ID]`. I removed all of the Individual Components before removing the Cloud SDK Core Command Line Tools Package.

Python includes an actual Windows uninstaller with its installation, you you can just remove it as normal via Add/Remove Programs.

Then, you can just Remove the Google Cloud SDK-related Environment Variables and the references in your `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 1):

To get Cloud SDK Uninstalled manually on WINDOWS(7 for me) :

Delete following two folders from your windows machine:

1. Cloud SDK Installation folder
   *** mostly found at standard installation folder- C:\Program Files (x86)\Google ***
   or custom location if you chose one during installation
2. Cloud SDK configuration folder in case you configured it after installation
   *** Default location is user-level AppData\Roaming\gcloud ***
   C:\Users{USERNAME}\AppData\Roaming\gcloud

Apart from this, I found entry of (Google) Cloud SDK in CONTROL PANEL-->Uninstall Programs too. Use this option to uninstall as well. It may throw alert if already deleted.

Last but not least:
Check your system environment variable "PATH". Remove any path that points to Cloud SDK locations.

Hope this would help windows user :)